# Linux rsyslog modification

Tags: rsyslog

I have configured `rsyslog` and set following value:

```
$template serverlog, "/var/log/TEST/%HOSTNAME%/server.log"
local4.* ?serverlog
```

Now the code will create folder based on `%HOSTNAME%`, but I would like to create folder First on server name (company name) and then `HOSTNAME`.

For example: I have 3 servers for the 2 different companies `ABCD` and `xyz`, and their 3 server names (hostname) is: `abcdapp-1t` `abcdapp-2t` `abcdapp-3t`

```
xyzapp-1t xyzapp-2t xyzapp-3t
```

Now if I run the above template, it will create different folders according to hostname under `/var/log/TEST/` , but I need to create 2 different folders `ABCD` and `XYZ` and relative hostname will go under specific directory and create subfolder.

For example: required to looks like this:

```
/var/log/TEST/ABCD/abcdapp-1t/server.log
/var/log/TEST/ABCD/abcdapp-2t/server.log
/var/log/TEST/ABCD/abcdapp-3t/server.log

/var/log/TEST/XYZ/xyzapp-1t/server.log
/var/log/TEST/XYZ/xyzapp-2t/server.log
/var/log/TEST/XYZ/xyzapp-3t/server.log
```

As I have more than 15 different servers of clients, I can not do it in one statement.

How can I use `If else IF` statements in `rsyslog` , so I can filter by `HOSTNAME` and move to specific folder?

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your HOSTNAME field is of the form *alphabetic-restofname* and the initial alphabetic part is your company name, you can separate it from the field using the [regexp property replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html#character-positions).  Change your template to

```
$template serverlog, "/var/log/TEST/%hostname:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([^-]+)--end%/%HOSTNAME%/server.log"
```

The regexp pattern is `([^-]+)`, meaning one or more characters not including `-`. The rest specifies that only the first capturing group `,1` of the `,ERE` extended regexp syntax should be kept. If there is no match the whole `FIELD` is kept.

You must have rsyslog version 3.19.5 or later,  or 4.1.5 or later. See the above link for changing to uppercase if wanted.

---

Alternatively, you should be able to do what you want, if your rsyslog is version 7 or later, using RainerScript as follows:

```
$template myplate,"/var/log/TEST/%$.customer%/%hostname%/server.log"
if ($hostname startswith "abcd") then set $.customer = "ABCD";
if ($hostname startswith "xyz") then set $.customer = "XYZ";
action(type="omfile" dynaFile="myplate")
stop
```

This creates a template using a local variable `$.customer`. The variable is set for each message when the hostname is matched by each `if` statement. The `action` writes the message to the calculated file. You can add another `if` statement for each customer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am not having fix pattern, having different host name and client name ..For example... HOSTNAME is gooapp-1t and  Client name is Googlie , .... HOSTNAME is yahapp-1t and Client name is Yahooiie.  Please provide any suggestion/ solution if possible.

Comment: As a simple solution you can use the regexp answer and then simply setup symbolic links from `/var/log/TEST/gooapp` to the real directory `var/log/TEST/Googlie` and so on.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick reply, but i am having more than 50 Clients and each having test , prod , dev app server. so its very difficult for me to link. Is there any way i can write a simple IF elseIF code in rsyslog.conf file...For Example .. IF HOSTNAME =  gooapp-1t then set Clientname = Googlie .......... and i will use variable Clientname under....$template serverlog, "/var/log/TEST/Clientname/%HOSTNAME%/server.log" ........some thing  like this

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative solution.